# Change Swing L&F at command line not work well

Tags: java, swing

I made an application with some widgets and at command line I want change their look and feel:

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel LookAndFeelAppl
```

but after invoked that command only a widget into the class constructor change its L&F but other that I created into a separate methods don't!!! Also tha JFrame itself not change.

public class LookAndFeelAppl extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

```
public LookAndFeelAppl()
{
    super("Look And Feel Demo");

    setLayout(null);

    final UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo plaf[] = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();

    JLabel lable_laf = new JLabel("Choose L&F:");
    final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();

    createOtherGUI();

    cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            int ix = cb.getSelectedIndex();
            try
            {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(plaf[ix].getClassName());
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(LookAndFeelAppl.this);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    });

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!! THIS LOOP GOES BEFORE
    // THE ITEMLISTENER BECAUSE WHEN I ADD ITEMS AN ITEMEVENT
    // IS RAISED THAT SET AGAIN THE L&F WITH setLookAndFeel!!!
    for (int i = 0, n = plaf.length; i < n; i++)
    {
      cb.addItem(plaf[i].getName());
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    add(lable_laf);
    add(cb);
    lable_laf.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 25);
    cb.setBounds(10, 35, 150, 25);
}

public void createOtherGUI()
{
    button = new JButton("BUTTON!!!!");
    add(button);
    button.setBounds(300, 45, 150, 35);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    LookAndFeelAppl window = new LookAndFeelAppl();
    window.setSize(1000, 700);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

}

Comment: So the createOtherGUI() does not work as it should? It would help if we had its source.

Comment: Doesn't compile. Does your class extend `JFrame` but you forgot to add this in your code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

I ran this in Eclipse (latest version) using JDK 1.6.0_13 on windows.  In the run configuration (VM arguments) of Eclipse I used `-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`

`public class Test extends JFrame {`

`public Test() {`

```
super("Test L&F");

JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});

getContentPane().add(box, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

createControls();

setSize(300, 300);
setVisible(true);
```

}

`private void createControls() {`

```
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});

getContentPane().add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

}

`public static void main(String[] args) {`
    `new Test();`
  `}
}`

Sorry, formatting is weird but you get the idea...

Comment: Ok I found the problem and you can see it into the complete code I posted. However two things I want tell you: first no matter, for a L&F if you use no layout manger, second when you use add method it automatically add components to the content pane. Read this: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/pane.html. Lastly, I want to thank you for you answers so +1 to your answer!

Comment: Thanks for the info (and the +1)!  I didn't realize that Sun (now Oracle ugg) "relented" on the content pane stuff (shows how long I've been using Java that I didn't know that this was included in 1.5!).  Again, thanks for the info and I'm glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

Few things to try and questions:

1. I see you are setting the L&F for windows, so I'm assuming you are running this on a windows box?  The reason I ask is I'm not sure what the JDK is supporting as far as cross-platform L&Fs, just something to think about.
2. Did you try other L&Fs with the same result?  (e.g. Nimbus)
3. This may or may not do anything but where do you have `main(...)`?  Try putting it in the JFrame and in a separate class that constructs the JFrame.
4. Worst comes to worse you could always pass the L&F classname in as an arg to `main(...)` (or a props file) then use the `UIManager` to set it BEFORE any swing components are created.

Good luck,
Dave

Comment: I'm in Windows and other J&Fs give the same results. The main is in the same class.

Comment: I created an app and it works fine for me.  I'm posting another answer so I can get formatting (can't figure out how with these comments)

Comment: Thanks soon I'll try it and then I tell you the results!

Comment: Really the only difference I see is your code is not using a layout manager (can't see why that would matter), the combo box in the constructor is marked as "final" (does not need to be unless you are doing something with it not in the example), and the combo box is being added straight to the JFrame instead of the content pane.  I thought that the JDK would throw a runtime error as components are suppose to be added to the content pane for swing components.